# Attaching event to multiple elements by Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a event to multiple elements, right now I have this code, it works, but I don't want to add a SetTimeout. If I take it away, it does not work.

Do you know why this is happening? Is there a better solution to this?

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var imageElements = document.querySelectorAll("img[class^='image']");
    for (var i = 0; i < imageElements.length; i++) {
        imageElements[i].addEventListener("click" , function(){
            definition(this.classList[0], this);
        })
    }
},200);
```

Comment: Is it possible this script is being executed before the actual elements are loaded? Is the script tag above the body of the html?

Comment: The images most likely haven't been loaded yet in the DOM. Hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: @Mvarta Yes, it is.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're trying to add the event handler to an element which is not yet created or ready in DOM.

Use the following, Your code should be inside `myFunction()`

```
window.addEventListener('load', myFunction, false )
```

For older versions of IE, it uses:

```
document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", myFunction);
//or
window.attachEvent("onload", myFunction);
```

Comment: can you try to use window.onload = myFunction; or use in your body's tag <body onload="myFunction"> .... </body>

Answer (score 0):

Using some ES6 arrow functions and forEach

```
let imageElements = document.querySelectorAll("img[class^='image']");

imageElements.forEach(image => image.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
    definition(this.classList[0], this); 
});
```